# Trying to get the value of an input within a container using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the `input` value from within a `mycontainer` div when a Click Me div is clicked.

I only want it to happen if the input is a `password` type, I have this so far...

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  theInput = $(el).closest("input type=['password]").value();
  console.log(theInput);
}
```

```css
.mycontainer {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="text" value="myinput1">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="password" value="myinput2">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="number" value="22">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="password" value="myinput4">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

This is throwing an error whenever I click anything, where am I going wrong?

Comment: um, `console.log(value);` but you store is in `theInput`

Comment: After you fix your naming issue, the code is not going to work because the input is not a parent of the button. Your selector is also wrong, that is not how you select an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your code. First you are looking for a parent. The input is not a parent, it is a sibling. So you can either look for a common parent with `closest()` and then look for the input with `find()`, you can use `siblings()`, or you can use `prev()`

Second your selector to find an input by attribute is wrong. The bracket needs to be around the entire attribute, not the value.

Third, there is no `.value()` in jQuery

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  const theInput = $(el).closest(".mycontainer").find('input[type="password"]');
  if (theInput.length) {
    console.log(theInput.val());
  }

  // other ways to reference the input
  console.log($(el).siblings('input[type="password"]').val());
  console.log($(el).prev('input[type="password"]').val());

}
```

```css
.mycontainer {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="text" value="myinput1">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="password" value="myinput2">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="number" value="22">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="password" value="myinput4">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have few issues in your code:

1. Your selector is not correct. You should first target the closest element with class `mycontainer` and find the password element from that. Since the attribute selector and the input element is same there should not be any space between them, also the attribute (`type`) should be inside the `[]`.
2. You are trying to access the value using `value()` on a jQuery referenced element (not a jQuery method), should use `val()`

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var theInput = $(el).closest(".mycontainer").find("input[type=password]").val();
  console.log(theInput);
}
```

```css
.mycontainer {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="text" value="myinput1">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="password" value="myinput2">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="number" value="22">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="password" value="myinput4">
  <div onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</div>
</div>
```